# prevent pydub from opening console window

Tags: windows, ffmpeg, pydub

Is there a way to prevent pydub from opening a console window when using ffmpeg (on Windows) ? Each time it launches ffmpeg to convert a mp3 file to wav, it briefly opens a console window that shuts down automatically when process is done but can be disturbing.

Comment: pydub runs ffmpeg in a subprocess - I don’t know much about windows, but maybe this little tidbit will help others answer?

Comment: In audio_segment.py I changed the two `p = subprocess.Popen(conversion_command, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)` lines, adding `creationflags=0x08000000`. This seems to be a fairly common way to avoid command windows being shown with these calls, so maybe that's worth putting into pydub itself if possible?

Comment: Just run ffmpeg manually.

Answer (score 3):

The solution I am using is to overload the `from_file` function. I just changed `subprocess` call, adding option `startupinfo`. Here are the few lines I added:

```
import platform  
systeme = platform.system()  
if systeme == 'Windows':  
    startupinfo = subprocess.STARTUPINFO()  
    startupinfo.dwFlags |= subprocess.STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW
    startupinfo.wShowWindow = subprocess.SW_HIDE
    p = subprocess.Popen(conversion_command, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, startupinfo=startupinfo)
else:  
    p = subprocess.Popen(conversion_command, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)`
```

Answer (score 0):

I do the following in any script which uses pydub:

Add `import subprocess` before import pydub

Then, just before I use pydub in the script I add:

`if subprocess.mswindows: subprocess.STARTUPINFO.dwFlags |= subprocess.STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW`

This tells any subprocess call from that script (whether or not through a pydub instruction) to not display a window by default, but to look to another flag called wShowWindow to decide whether to display. As that flag is 0 by default, the window isn't shown.

note: `dwFlags` is no longer a class attribute but an instance attribute of `STARTUPINFO` (on newer Python versions like 3.9) therefore this answer isn't working for new versions. A `STARTUPINFO()` object must be created.

Answer (score 0):

You can modify the source code and recompile it at runtime.

```py
# Created by BaiJiFeiLong@gmail.com at 2022/2/18 22:09
import importlib.util
import re
import sys
import types

import pydub
from IceSpringPathLib import Path

for moduleName in "pydub.utils", "pydub.audio_segment":
    spec = importlib.util.find_spec(moduleName, None)
    source = spec.loader.get_source(moduleName)
    snippet = "__import__('subprocess').STARTUPINFO(dwFlags=__import__('subprocess').STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW)"
    source, n = re.subn(r"(Popen)\((.+?)\)", rf"\1(\2, startupinfo=print('worked') or {snippet})", source, flags=re.DOTALL)
    module = importlib.util.module_from_spec(spec)
    exec(compile(source, module.__spec__.origin, "exec"), module.__dict__)
    sys.modules[moduleName] = module
module = importlib.reload(sys.modules["pydub"])
for k, v in module.__dict__.items():
    if isinstance(v, types.ModuleType):
        setattr(module, k, importlib.import_module(v.__name__))

pydub.audio_segment.AudioSegment.from_file(Path("~/Music").expanduser().glob("**/*.mp3").__next__())
```